# Using tablet to start python script

Tags: python, telegram, tablet, python-telegram-bot

With regards of my knowledge regarding programming, i know windows is the most optimal to start the python script. However, i want to know am i able to use other device to start the program? such as Samsung tablet or iPad, as i want to start the program. I know that to run the program forever, it is required to use a spare laptop/desktop or a server, however am i able to run it from my tablet 24/7?

I am currently trying to run a telegram bot, however i am looking for other ways to be able to do this on-the-go without having to use my desktop to run it, as for tablet i can run it anytime i want it to.

Comment: How do you know that the windows is the most optimal to start the python script? What does that even mean? Regarding your question you could try amazon web services or some other cloud service that can act as a server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it on your tablet you need to download an application like [Pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=en) and run the script from there. However it might be difficult to keep it running... never tried something like that.

Personally I would use [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?trk=ps_a134p000003yhTZAAY&trkCampaign=acq_paid_search_brand&sc_channel=ps&sc_campaign=acquisition_BENELUX&sc_publisher=google&sc_category=core&sc_country=BENELUX&sc_geo=&sc_outcome=Acquisition&sc_detail=%2Baws%20%2Bfree&sc_content=Cost_bmm&sc_matchtype=b&sc_segment=458573551573&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CAWS%7CCore%7CBENELUX%7CEN%7CText&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!458573551573!b!!g!!%2Baws%20%2Bfree&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw8fr7BRDSARIsAK0Qqr6Y_3XKo74vgvayYpplxKUIZdBa-_pmES-otFoOzChygBf3WO3WD-waArMbEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!458573551573!b!!g!!%2Baws%20%2Bfree&all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc), you can have a small virtual machine with 1 core and 2 gb of ram for free, you could run your bot there 24/7 without any worries.
See